# Array doesn't appear to be holding data

Tags: php, mysql

I have a system where I rearrange navigational items.

It stores the new order in an array and then I use a for loop to go through the array and update the database.

```
<?php
$apageid = array();
$apagename = array();
$apageorder = array();

$q = "SELECT g.id, g.title, n.order FROM tbl_general g INNER JOIN tbl_navigation n ON n.pageid = g.id WHERE n.type = '$_SESSION[parent]' ORDER BY n.order";
$return = $database->query($q);
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($return)){
    $apageid[] = $row['id'];
    $apagename[] = $row['title'];
    $apageorder[] = $row['order'];
}

$count = count($apageid);
$bpageid = array();
$bpageorder = array();
?>
<div class="form-holder">
<?php

//run through each page one at a time and update the order of the menu
mysql_data_seek( $return, 0 ); //reset the pointer to do the same query
$i = 0; //the count for saving the new configuration
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($return)){

    $id = $row['id'];
    $title = $row['title'];
    $order = $row['order'];
    ?>
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="form-label">
            Page Name
        </div>
        <div class="form-field">
            <select class="select-small" name="<?php echo $bpageid[$i]; ?>">
                <?php
                for($j=0; $j<$count; $j++){
                    if($apageid[$j] == $id) {
                        $selected = true;
                    } else {
                        $selected = false;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $apageid[$j]; ?>" <? echo ($selected == true) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $apagename[$j]; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
            <select class="select-small" name="<?php echo $bpageorder[$i]; ?>">
                <?php
                for($k=0; $k<$count; $k++){
                    if($apageorder[$k] == $order) {
                        $selected = true;
                    } else {
                        $selected = false;
                    }
                    ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $apageorder[$k]; ?>" <? echo ($selected == true) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; ?>><?php echo $apageorder[$k]; ?></option>
                    <?php
                }
                ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php
    $i++;
}
?>
```

This first chunk of code is the menu where you can reorder items.

Initially it loads up the current select and allows you to change the ordering.

```
function reorderChildren($pageid, $pageorder){
    global $database;

    $count = count($pageid);
    //run through each page one at a time and update the order of the menu
    for($i=0; $i<$count; $i++){
        //set a few variables
        $pid = $pageid[$i];
        $porder = $pageorder[$i];
        echo "pid = $pid porder = $porder";
        $q = "UPDATE tbl_navigation SET order = '$porder' WHERE pageid = '$pid' AND type = '$_SESSION[parent]'";
        $database->query($q);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The information then ends up being passed here and the problem appears to be the for loop is never executed.

Can anyone see why this would be?

It's not the naming used, I've checked them.

Am I storing information in the arrays correctly?

Can I make it clear that it's `$bpageid` and `$bpageorder` that are the arrays carrying the information forward.

Thanks!

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but you might [want to look at this](http://bobby-tables.com/).

Comment: It's a secure form, admin only access.

Answer (score 1):

Was a simple fix!
The problem was that the select name needed to be just name="bpageid[]" rather than what I listed above. Silly!

Answer (score 0):

You have just initilized `$bpageid = array();` at top after first while loop.No value is assigned

after that you using

```
<select class="select-small" name="<?php echo $bpageid[$i]; ?>">
```

but no value is in `$bpageid[$i]` so name of this select box is blank.

It might be problem. check this and do as required.

Comment: Can you suggest an alternative way to do this then? I'm trying to find a way to save the values of the select elements and pass them through. The amount of select values will change though dependant on how many are currently added.

Answer (score 0):

you could try to construct a json from the options of the select element store it to a hidden field or send ajax request to php script for processing , order could be made from a "weight" value 1,2,3 etc.... sort it with php and loop to display

Comment: I don't really understand what you are suggesting. Not very knowledgable with JSON!

Comment: www.w3schools.com/json/json_intro.asp
an example of json , json_decode() is a php function that will decode your json string for use in php